How can I do SSR with React and Laravel? My project is in Laravel and React. For SEO purpose I want to implement SSR. I don't want to do it in Next.js
resources/js/app.js
import './bootstrap';
import './components/Main';

resources/js/components/Main.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import  store  from './store.js'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import SecondHeader from './app/SecondHeader.jsx';
import App from './App.jsx';

let persistor = persistStore(store)

function Main() {
    const clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info"))
    console.log('Main.jsx route has been hit');
    return (
        <>
        {/* <Header /> */}
        <SecondHeader></SecondHeader>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
            </Routes>
        <Footer />
        </>
    );
}
export default Main;

if (document.getElementById('root')) {
    console.log('Main.jsx has been hit');
    const container = document.getElementById("root");

    ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
        container,
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                    <Main/>
                </PersistGate>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
}

resources/js/components/App.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App({ initialUsers = [] }) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(initialUsers);
  console.log('App component in App.jsx is being rendered');
  // console.log('Initial Users up in App.jsx:', initialUsers);
  console.log('Initial Users up in App.jsx:', initialUsers.slice(0, 1));
  useEffect(() => {
    
    // Only fetch if there are no users provided via SSR
    if (users.length === 0) { // Avoid fetching if users are already set
      console.log('Not fetching data from server.js')
      fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setUsers(data))
        .catch(err => console.error("Error fetching users:", err));
    }
  }, [users]); // Depend on users

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Users List</h2>
      <ul>
        {users.length > 0 ? (
          users.map((user, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{user.title}</li>
          ))
        ) : (
          <li>Loading users...</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

resources/js/components/entry-server.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { renderToPipeableStream } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from '/resources/js/components/App';

/**
 * @param {string} url
 * @param {string} [ssrManifest]
 * @param {import('react-dom/server').RenderToPipeableStreamOptions} [options]
 */

console.log('Entry server is being rendered')
export function render(url, ssrManifest, { initialUsers, onShellReady, onShellError, onError }) {
    console.log('Entry server render function is being rendered')
  return renderToPipeableStream(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App initialUsers={initialUsers} />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    {
      onShellReady() {
        if (onShellReady) onShellReady();
      },
      onShellError(err) {
        if (onShellError) onShellError(err);
      },
      onError(err) {
        if (onError) onError(err);
      }
    }
  );
}

server.js
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';
import express from 'express';
import { Transform } from 'node:stream';

// Constants
console.log('this is the server up 1')
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const port = process.env.PORT || 5173;
const base = process.env.BASE || '/';
const ABORT_DELAY = 10000;

// Cached production assets
const templateHtml = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile('./dist/client/index.html', 'utf-8')
  : '';
const ssrManifest = isProduction
  ? JSON.parse(await fs.readFile('./dist/client/.vite/ssr-manifest.json', 'utf-8'))
  : undefined;

// Create http server
const app = express();

// Add Vite or respective production middlewares
let vite;
if (!isProduction) {
  const { createServer } = await import('vite');
  vite = await createServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: 'custom',
    base,
  });

  
  app.use(vite.middlewares);
} else {
  const compression = (await import('compression')).default;
  const sirv = (await import('sirv')).default;
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(base, sirv('./dist/client', { extensions: [] }));
}

// Serve HTML with SSR
console.log('this is the server 2')
app.use('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('this is the server')
    const url = req.originalUrl.replace(base, '');

    let template;
    let render;
    if (!isProduction) {
      // Always read fresh template in development
    //   template = await fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8');
      template = await fs.readFile('./resources/views/layouts/front-end/master.blade.php', 'utf-8');
      template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template);
      render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule('/resources/js/components/entry-server.jsx')).render;
      console.log('this is the production server')
    } else {
      template = templateHtml;
      render = (await import('/dist/server/entry-server.js')).render;
      console.log('this is the local server')
    }

    // Fetch user data from the server
    let initialUsers = [];
    try {
      const userResponse = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
      const userData = await userResponse.json();
      initialUsers = userData;
      // console.log('Got products form server.js')
      console.log('Got products form server.js: ', initialUsers.slice(0, 1))
    } catch (fetchError) {
      console.error('Error fetching users:', fetchError);
    }

    let didError = false;

    const { pipe, abort } = render(url, ssrManifest, {
      initialUsers, // Pass the fetched users here
      onShellError() {
        res.status(500);
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.send('<h1>Something went wrong</h1>');
      },
      onShellReady() {
        res.status(didError ? 500 : 200);
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        console.log('Inside server.js and on shell ready')

        const transformStream = new Transform({
          transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            res.write(chunk, encoding);
            callback();
          }
        });

        const [htmlStart, htmlEnd] = template.split(`<!--app-html-->`);

        // Write start of the HTML
        res.write(htmlStart);

        // Pipe the stream and append the closing HTML
        transformStream.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('Html adding in server.js')
            // res.write(`
            //     <script type="module" src="/assets/entry-client.js"></script>
            //   `);
            res.end(htmlEnd);
        });

        pipe(transformStream); // Pipe the rendered stream
      },
      onError(error) {
        didError = true;
        console.error(error);
      },
    });

    // Abort the stream after a delay to avoid hanging connections
    setTimeout(() => {
      abort();
    }, ABORT_DELAY);
  } catch (e) {
    vite?.ssrFixStacktrace(e);
    console.log(e.stack);
    res.status(500).end(e.stack);
  }
});

// Start http server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at http://127.0.0.1:${port}`);
});

vite.config.js
import { build, defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                // 'resources/js/components/entry-client.jsx',
                // 'resources/js/components/entry-server.jsx',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react()
        
    ],
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600,
      }
});
console.log('Vite is running.')

resources/views/layouts/front-end/master.blade.php
<div id="root"><!--app-html--></div>

package.json
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"vite\" \"node server.js\"",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "vite build --ssrManifest --outDir dist/client",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr resources/js/components/entry-server.jsx --outDir dist/server",
    "preview": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server"
  },

laravel web.php
Route::get('{any}', function () {
    // This will make a request to your Node server to get the SSR HTML
    $ssr = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:5173'); // Node server URL
    return $ssr;
})->where('any', '.*');

Here, is my code. I havae implemented SSR. When I hit http://127.0.0.1:5173/ directly I get the html in the view source, but when I hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/ the html is not being rendered in the view source page. After debugging, I found that on hitting both the server I am getting the data in App.jsx from server.js (from console in the terminal). However, I am not getting the data in the browser console from http://127.0.0.1:8000/ i.e. console.log('Initial Users up in App.jsx:', initialUsers.slice(0, 1)); this statement from App.jsx is returning an empty array. I think the browser page is being rendered before the server.js file is being executed. Now I am not sure where I made the mistake. It would be much appreciated if anyone could help me. Thank you

Why people want to make it complicated when frameworks already work for you ?  NextJS, Nuxt, are created and maintained by thousand of people. Use them, understand the limits of SSR using JS frameworks, if your app is small, use other option. Don't try it by yourself.
